# Unity: Combine two UVs by alpha

Tags: unity, voxels, blending

I'm currently creating a voxel game like Minecraft. To display the damage of blocks, I want to combine the alpha channel of one part of my texture map with the actual texture (like Minecraft does), how could I do that in Unity?

Comment: shader code: `final_color.rgb = lerp(block_texture_color.rgb,damage_texture_color.rgb,damage_texture_color.a * damage_factor)` and `damage_factor` is a float 0 or 1 depending if you want to see the block damaged or not (you can pass it trough alpha color from vertex color or via a uniform

Comment: Thanks for the code!, My problem is that my world is divided into chunks, as far as I know, you can only attach shaders to the entire chunk gameobject, how could I target only the damaged block?